# Falla en Print @query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo este trozo de query, el error se encuentra en la forma que muestra la informacion,
en que la parte del from no es seleccionada completamente, el error la corta a la mitad, invalid object name "Temp_" a veces "Te" y las ultimas ocasiones dice que hay un error de syntaxis cerca del from, pero no logro encontrar el error, podria alguien ilustrarme

```
     WHILE @cnt <= (SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM #columns)
BEGIN
 IF @column NOT IN ('DAYS','ITEMS','ID')
    BEGIN
        SET @query  = 
            'INSERT INTO Temp_IDENT_002 
            SELECT 
            TARGET ='+ CAST(@TARGET_ID AS VARCHAR) +',
            T1.DAYS,
            T1.ITEMS,
            T1.ID,
            T1.COLUMN_NAME,
            SUBSTRING(CAST(T1.COLUMN_VALUE AS VARCHAR), 0, 250) AS COLUMN_VALUE
        FROM Temp_IDENT_001 WITH (NOLOCK) /* <-------------- */
            UNPIVOT
            ( COLUMN_VALUE
        FOR COLUMN_NAME IN
        ( ['+ @column +']
            ) ) T1
        ORDER BY T1.DAYS'
    print @query
        EXECUTE(@query)
    END
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Comment: Agrega la salida del ` print @query` a tu pregunta en el caso del error. Además como está definido `@query`?

Comment: ¿El INSERT de la tabla lo haces sin definir los nombres de las columnas? ¿Las columnas son fijas y son todas las de la tabla? sino es así, probalemente ahí este el problema.

Comment: de la tabla del unpivot, se detecta de forma dinamica, sea cual sea que la cambien, es el proposito del query

Comment: Ok, eso significa que la cantidad de columnas es variable, si es así la  clausula de INSERT te exige que indiques los nombres `insert into tabla (c1, c2, c3) select c1, c2, cr ...` y veo que no lo estás haciendo. Mas allá de este comentario,  lo que tienes es la construcción de una sentencia dinámica que que es correcta, el problema es la consulta final que se genera, que es lo que falla ver, si no muestras como te decía, la salida del `print @query`  es poco lo que podemos hacer para ayudarte

Comment: te referias a esta pregunta del stack overflow cierto? si es asi quedo listo, mas me hace logica que el print sea lo que esta fallando

Comment: aunque, no es dinamica con columnas, sino con fillas

Comment: No, no es que falle el print, lo que falla es la consulta que se crea dinámicamente, que es lo que habría que mirar, por eso te digo que nos muestres el valor final de @query ya que ahí adentro está el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes viene determinado por la longitud de la variable `@query` que no vemos definida en el código que muestras. Debes poner un tamaño mayor, me imagino que estará definida como `varchar`

```
declare @query varchar(max)
```

Con el `max` te curas en salud, aunque probablemente un `varchar(1000)` sería suficiente.

Comment: funciono!!! mil gracias!